# IIS 7,.NET framework 4. I am getting the following error even though there is no syntax error. Can anyone please suggesta solution?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Parser Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Source Error: (in line 99)

Line 97:
Line 98: 
Line 99:

Comment: Line 97:</td>
Line 98:  <td class="mid" style="text-align:center;">
Line 99:  <span style="margin-right: 25px;"><asp:Button ID="btnDefLogin" runat="server" CssClass="button_middle" ToolTip="Log-in to the Web interface" OnClick="OnBnLogin" OnClientClick="needToConfirm=false;"  OnMouseOver="button_over(this);" OnMouseOut="button_out(this);" onmousedown="button_down(this);" onmouseup="button_up(this)"; /></span>
Line 100:                                <span style="margin-right: 25px;"><asp:Button ID="btnDefPostFlt" runat="server" Text="test" CssClass="button_middle"

Comment: This is not clear.. share your code more to understand what actually your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You had write `onmouseup="button_up(this)";` instead of `onmouseup="button_up(this);"`, Delimiter `;` must be inside in double quote.

Replace your line number 99 with below code:

```
<span style="margin-right: 25px;">
                <asp:Button 
                    ID="btnDefLogin" 
                    runat="server" 
                    CssClass="button_middle" 
                    ToolTip="Log-in to the Web interface" 
                    OnClick="OnBnLogin" 
                    OnClientClick="needToConfirm=false;" 
                    OnMouseOver="button_over(this);" 
                    OnMouseOut="button_out(this);" 
                    onmousedown="button_down(this);" 
                    onmouseup="button_up(this);" /></span>
```